# Pasting content into iframe with designMode on in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, contenteditable, copy-paste

We have identified a problem with editable iframes in Internet Explorer 9 and 10 (it may also occur in other versions but thus far have not been able to confirm).

If you create a simple iframe with designMode set to on, type a couple of words, and then paste some complex content in (in this example, an email including signature directly from Outlook, or a formatted document from MS Word), then upon modifying the original content, characters typed become invisible until space is pressed or focus is lost from the iframe.

What is more bizarre about the behaviour is that if the user presses return **before** pasting their content, then the problem does not occur. Also, performing the same steps in a content editable DIV does not result in the same problem (however, putting an editable DIV inside a non-editable iframe **does** result in the problem, so the iframe definitely appears to be the problem).

The problem does not occur in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox and the only workaround seems to be to ensure that there is a line break between the initial content and the pasted content.

I have also just noticed that the behaviour can be replicated **very** easily by ensuring that the iframe scrolls. The following code will replicate:

```
<iframe id="theframe" style="height:50px;"></iframe>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('theframe');
        iframe.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
    });
</script>
```

I have also setup a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/z76x7gzL/ that reliably replicates the problem.

In the fiddle, if you type "this is a test" followed by a space and then pasting at least 2 lines from Word, then go back to the end of the "this is a test" line and attempt to type, the text will be invisible.

Any help much appreciated,

Comment: My browser happens to be IE11 and I followed all the steps you mentioned. I don't experience the issue

Comment: Hi @RomanCanlas, I don't currently have access to IE11 but will do when I get home, so I will try it then and update here if I manage to replicate in 11 or not.

Comment: @RomanCanlas I have just got home and tested in IE11 and can confirm that it doesn't seem to occur. So looks like it may be a bug in 9 and 10, I will see if I can test it in 7 and 8.